# Correct way of presenting a ViewController B from ViewController A before A is visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My iOS App starts with `UIViewController A` which is embedded as first element in a `UINavigationController`. When the app is started or when returning to it after some time in background I would like to show a password prompt. In this case `UIViewController A` should present `UIViewController B` which shows the password prompt.

The user should immediately see `UIViewController B`, not A and then B sliding in, etc. Thus, I have presented `UIViewController B` in `viewWillAppear` in `UIViewController A`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if needPassword {           
        let passwordVC = PasswordViewController()
        passwordVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(passwordVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This works fine, but an error message is logged:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7fe9af01c200>.
```

It is obvious that presenting `UIViewController B` from `UIViewController A` before it became visible causes this problem. Moving from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` would solve the error message. However, than the user would first see A then B...

**Is it even possible to overlay a ViewControler A with ViewController B without A becoming visible first?**

I know that there might be other solutions like adding the view of the password ViewController manually to the view hierachy, etc. However, I would prefer a clean way where A is in complete control. Is this possible?

**Or is it save to simple ignore the warning?**

Comment: Ignore `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` as it sometimes miss-leading

Comment: How about adding a view inside the navigation controller view then embed your PasswordViewController into that view as a child controller?

Comment: The destination controller is a navigation controller?

Comment: Have you tried to add code in viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: son, while this would certainly work, it is hacky solution as mentioned in my question. Is there a "clean" approach?
Fabio: You mean wether passwordVC is a NavigationController? No just a plain UIViewController. 
@RahulPhate Please read the question...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit tricky, might do the job though.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if needPassword {           
        self.view.alpha = 0

        // Maybe (or not?)
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if needPassword {           
        let passwordVC = PasswordViewController()
        passwordVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(passwordVC, animated: false, completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```